# How to make the end of loop more readable in Ruby

Tags: ruby

There are some blocks in my code.

To make it easier to read, I often append comment after the end

such as

```
  end # end upto
  end # fileopen
```

Because sometimes the indentation still not easy for read.

Is there any better practice?

And my indentation is 2 spaces, is it OK for most Rubier ?

```
require "faker"
real_sn = 2124100000
File.open("lib/tasks/tw_books.txt", "r").each do |line|
  # author = Faker::Lorem.words(2..5).join(' ').gsub('-','').gsub('\s+','\s')

  1.upto(1000).each do |x|

    location = Faker::Lorem.words(5)
    book_name, author, publisher, isbn, comment = line.strip.split("|||")
    ap(line)
    isbn = isbn[/\d+/]
    real_sn+=1
    bk = Book.new(:sn => real_sn,:name => book_name, :isbn=>isbn,
                  :price =>Random.rand(200..5000), :location=>location, :category=>["商業","歷史","體育","政治"].sample,
                  :author => author, :sale_type => [:fix_priced, :normal, :promotion].sample, :publisher => publisher,
                  :release_date => rand(10.years).ago, :comment => comment
                  )
    if bk.save()
      if (real_sn%100)==0
        puts book_name
      end
      Sunspot.commit
    else
      puts real_sn
      puts bk.errors.full_messages
    end
  end # end upto
end # fileopen
```

Comment: Refactor for readability. The trailing comments are irritating and do nothing for readability, they only detract.

Comment: @DaveNewton: Trailing `end` comments are irritating for blocks shorter than ~10 lines, and valuable for long blocks, such as module and class definitions. Fortran authors were not completely insane for making the `END` "comments" mandatory.

Comment: @BorisStitnicky If a block is that long it's almost always missing one or more refactorings. Use normal docs at the *beginning* of classes and modules for visual separation. When we wrote Fortran we wrote in a very different style-and it's not a language feature that survived as we moved forward.

Comment: @DaveNewton: ... module and class definitions ...

Comment: @BorisStitnicky ... They're not valuable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Compare your code to how I'd write it:

```
require "faker"

real_sn = 2124100000

File.open("lib/tasks/tw_books.txt", "r").each do |line|
# author = Faker::Lorem.words(2..5).join(' ').gsub('-','').gsub('\s+','\s')

  1.upto(1000).each do |x|

    location = Faker::Lorem.words(5)
    book_name, author, publisher, isbn, comment = line.strip.split("|||")

    ap(line)

    isbn = isbn[/\d+/]
    real_sn += 1

    bk = Book.new(
      :author => author,
      :category =>["商業","歷史","體育","政治"].sample,
      :comment => comment,
      :isbn => isbn,
      :location =>location,
      :name => book_name,
      :price => Random.rand(200..5000),
      :publisher => publisher,
      :release_date => rand(10.years).ago,
      :sale_type => [
        :fix_priced,
        :normal,
        :promotion
      ].sample,
      :sn => real_sn,
    )

    if bk.save()

      puts book_name if ((real_sn % 100) == 0)
      Sunspot.commit

    else

      puts real_sn
      puts bk.errors.full_messages

    end
  end
end
```

Part of writing code is making it readable and maintainable. That means use indentation, vertical alignment, whitespace between operators, vertical whitespace to make changes in logic more obvious, etc.

I sort hash keys alphabetically, such as the parameters for `Book.new`, especially when there's a lot of them. This makes it a lot easier to see if something is duplicated or missing. Since it's a hash it doesn't matter what order they're in as far as Ruby is concerned; Again this is for maintenance later on.

The editor you use can help you immensely with this. I use [gvim](http://vim.org) and [Sublime Text](http://www.sublimetext.com/), both of which allow me to easily reformat/reindent code I'm working on, and I take advantage of that often. It's a good first step when you have code from a "foreign source" that makes your eyes bug out. Reindent it, fix long, awkward sections, like your list of hash entries for `Book.new`, and the code will become more understandable.

Also, your editor needs to have the ability to jump between matching delimiters like `()`, `[]`, `{}` and `do`/`end`. gvim can do that plus jump through `if`/`else`/`end` plus `rescue` blocks. That ability to navigate REALLY helps keep your code flow clear.

Comment: I noticed that you left the comments at the end of the `end` statements.  Is that really how you would write this, or did you just leave it in?

Comment: No, I wouldn't use comments on `end`. If I have to do that to figure out logic or control structures I haven't written it clearly enough up above. Those were there as left-overs; I was mostly showing everything above the final close of the blocks. I'll take them out for thoroughness.

Answer (score 1):

To provide an alternative to the respected Tin Man's answer, commenting `end`s is a practice that I use when the block body is long (yours is longish). When the body is short, commenting `end`s is unnecessary. I would write your code as:

```
require "faker"
real_sn = 2124100000

File.open( 'lib/tasks/tw_books.txt', ?r ).each do |line|
  # author = Faker::Lorem.words( 2..5 ).join( ' ' ).gsub( '-', '' ).gsub( '\s+', '\s' )
  1.upto( 1000 ).each do |x|
    location = Faker::Lorem.words( 5 )
    book_name, author, publisher, isbn, comment = line.strip.split( "|||" )
    ap( line )
    isbn = isbn[ /\d+/ ]
    real_sn += 1
    bk = Book.new( sn: real_sn, name: book_name, isbn: isbn,
                   author: author, publisher: publisher,
                   location: location,
                   category: %w[ 商業 歷史 體育 政治 ].sample,
                   sale_type: %i[fix_priced normal promotion].sample,
                   release_date: rand( 10.years ).ago,
                   price: Random.rand( 200 .. 5000 ),
                   comment: comment )
    if bk.save then
      puts book_name if real_sn % 100 == 0
      Sunspot.commit
    else
      puts real_sn
      puts bk.errors.full_messages
    end
  end # end upto
end # File.open
```

You can notice a few mainly cosmetic changes, such as colon notation in `keyword: arguments`, spaces inside parenthesis (I find it more readable), word array and symbol array literals...

*Reusable* code is write once, read many times. When writing reusable code, one should make it brief, but not by using abbreviations of common words, or by cramming characters together. Conversely, when writing one-time code, it is OK to use abbreviations and save keystrokes. I hope that you do not reuse your code example much. If you do, you should refactor it into [2 or 3 smaller methods](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?ComposedMethod), or even [method object(s)](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?MethodObject).

The editor you use can help you immensly. Matz uses [Emacs](http://www.emacswiki.org/). In fact, [he was inspired by Emacs](http://www.slideshare.net/yukihiro_matz/how-emacs-changed-my-life) when creating Ruby. Emacs gives one everything expected of a programming editor. In fact, Emacs gives you power, for the price of having to actually read the manual. With Emacs, I use `yasnippet` for code snippets, and `auto-complete-el` as the most intelligent auto completion agent. One other modification that makes life in `Emacs` easy is [redefining Caps Lock to be a Ctrl key](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs-ru/CapsKey#toc4).

Apart from that, the Ruby style manual that I found valuable is [the one by Ian McDonald from Google](http://www.caliban.org/ruby/rubyguide.shtml).